# Changing Text Area string colors in javaFX using the ColorPicker

Tags: javafx, color-picker

I am trying to use the ColorPicker in JavafX to change the color of current text in a TextArea. Is there something like JavaSwing to change foreground color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the value of the text area using `setStyle` on value change of the `ColorPicker`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Text Sample");
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
        textArea.setPrefSize(200, 40);

        final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
        colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldColor, newColor) ->
            textArea.setStyle(
              "-fx-text-fill: " + toRgbString(newColor) + ";"
            )
        );

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(new VBox(textArea, colorPicker), 300, 250)
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    private String toRgbString(Color c) {
        return "rgb("
                          + to255Int(c.getRed())
                    + "," + to255Int(c.getGreen())
                    + "," + to255Int(c.getBlue())
             + ")";
    }

    private int to255Int(double d) {
        return (int) (d * 255);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to use the color value from the JavFX color picker, the method works on some color, but not others. This is one of the errors:                                                     WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser term CSS Error parsing in-line style '-fx-text-fill: 334db3;' from javafx.scene.Node$22@4f7ceeaa: Unexpected token '334db' at [1,15]
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper transitionToState Failed to set css [StyleableProperty {property: -fx-text-fill, converter: PaintConverter, initalValue: 0x000000ff, inherits: false, subProperties: []}]

Comment: Yes. I agree to your point above. Please see this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea) on how to pass the value for the attribute to be set, as this attribute is not mentioned straight away in the text area API.

Comment: I think i'll just hack it and hard code a list of colors from the CSS types since I am only developing a prototype and don't the luxury of time to learn how CSS really works!

Comment: Edited code to work in a wider variety of circumstances (also used Java 8 syntax).

Comment: I am getting an error for the .addListener method constructor... any ideas?

Comment: Pls provide a little more information on the error you are getting. Most likely it is a wrong import.